# Display All Gridview control values when i clear my textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a text box control and a Grid view control on my web form. The text box is used to search for specific records in the Grid view. What i would like to do now is that when i clear my text box then i want all the original Grid view values to appear inside the Grid view. Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On clear button click, add code to bind the grid again.
If you have any particular scenario, please update your query with code